# A committee consists of five Chicanos, two Asians,... How many subcommittees of five can be created..Feedback

Tags: combinatorics

A committee consists of five Chicanos, two Asians, three African Americans, and two Caucasians. How many subcomittees of five can be created where each subcommittee consists of all the ethnic groups?

I know what the solution is, but I want to know why my approach didn't work?....What did I double count ?

My solution:

$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{8}{1}$$

The solution I've seen breaks it down as follows:

$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1} + \binom{5}{1}\binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1} + \binom{5}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1} + \binom{5}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}$$

My view is that if we don't care what the ethnicity is of the fifth member why can't we just multiply?

Comment: What do you mean by "just multiply"?  You have to consider the three cases where the 5th member is Asian, African American, and Caucasian, and theres three African Americans opposed to two Caucasians and Asians so they're not "symmetric" and hence you can't multiply one case by three if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you have them ordered in the sense that at the end you choose one from the eight remaining. For example, let $(a,b,c,d,e)$ be one of your solutions, where $a$ is Chicano, $b$ is Asian, $c$ is african american, $d$ is Caucasian an $e$ is also say Chicano. Notice that this comitee is counted once but also you are counting this one $(e,b,c,d,a)$ because you could have chosen $e$ as the chicano and then $a$ from the remainder.

Comment: Ah that's where my fault in logic came....Thanks for the help